# Android: AsyncTask onPreExecute() method is NOT executed in UI thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I have an AsyncTask **executed from a thread**. In `onPreExecute()` method i want to change some `TextView`s but i get the following errors (recap):

```
05-07 11:53:02.039: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): FATAL EXCEPTION: processBarcodeThread
05-07 11:53:02.039: E/AndroidRuntime(7062): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
.....
05-07 11:53:02.039: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2573)
05-07 11:53:02.039: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at it.mbm.droid.activity.fragment.LabelAnagFragment$ReadFromServerTask.onPreExecute(LabelAnagFragment.java:301)
05-07 11:53:02.039: E/AndroidRuntime(7062):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
```

This means that `onPreExecute()` is not executed on UI thread, but according to Android documentation:

> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.

So, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: plz also show onPreExecute method code

Comment: are you referencing it from doInBackground()?

Comment: This says it all: _Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views_. Move the `setText()` part to the `onPostExecute()` and you will be good to go.

Comment: well, looking at the AsyncTask source code, the method `onPreExecute` is called on the thread who called `execute` on AsyncTask.
Look at [AsyncTask](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.execute%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: please provide the code from where you start the async task. You might be calling the async task from some other thread

Comment: In the onPreExecute method i simply set  a string in a TextView (txtView.setText(aString)). @user2340612 i have thought the same thing.. but why in Android doc is written "onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed" if it is not always true!?!?

Comment: Well I don't know :) If you can access the Activity from your AsyncTask you can use `activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` to accomplish your task.

Comment: yes, it was what i did.Thank you the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be calling `execute()` on your `AsyncTask` from a background thread. If you read the documentation for `AsyncTask`, you will see that this is not supported:

> There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class
>   to work properly:
>
> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done
>     automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - The task instance must be created on
>     the UI thread.
> - execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
>     ...

Hence, please change your code to call `execute()` on your `AsyncTask` from the main application thread.

Comment: Well, technically it's kind of supported. It doesn't throw an error if you execute an AsyncTask from doInBackground of another AsyncTask. You just won't be on the Thread you expect when onPostExecute is called. Is the documentation a warning to prevent unexpected results? Or is there some other threading issue at work if you don't heed the warning in the docs?

Comment: @ChristopherPerry: "You just won't be on the Thread you expect when onPostExecute is called" -- it certainly used to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try put changes into onProgressUpdate method. Something like:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {    

                    publishProgress("putThisStringToTextView");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        updateTextView(values[0]);
    }

    private void updateTextView(String text) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        final TextView myTextView = ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_txt_view));
         if (textView == null) {
        return;
     }
         textView.setText(text);
         this.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probable failed in on of these steps:

The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of
Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
.
The task instance must be created on the UI thread.

execute(java.lang.Object[]) must be invoked on the UI thread.